How to fix this error: KeyError: 'model.embed_tokens.weight'
This is the detailed error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cyq/zxc/SmartEdit/train/DS_MLLMSD11_train.py", line 769, in <module>
    train()
  File "/home/cyq/zxc/SmartEdit/train/DS_MLLMSD11_train.py", line 540, in train
    model_.load_pretrain_MLLM_alignment(SD_QFormer_conversation_33tokens=SD_QFormer_conversation_33tokens, LLaVA_00002=LLaVA_00002)
  File "/home/cyq/zxc/SmartEdit/model/DS_MLLMSD11_model.py", line 227, in load_pretrain_MLLM_alignment
    LLaMA_word2vec = weights.pop('model.embed_tokens.weight')
KeyError: 'model.embed_tokens.weight'

In this code, I first initialized the qformer, and I want to load the pre-trained weights of qformer from this path: '/SmartEdit-7B/embeddings_qformer/checkpoint-15000_embeddings_qformer.bin'. However, I encountered this problem when loading the weights. The loading code is as follows:
 def load_pretrain_MLLM_alignment(self, SD_QFormer_conversation_33tokens, LLaVA_00002):
        weights = torch.load(SD_QFormer_conversation_33tokens, map_location="cpu")
        LLaVA_00002_weights = torch.load(LLaVA_00002, map_location="cpu")
        print('mm_projector weight:', weights['mm_projector.weight'] == LLaVA_00002_weights['model.mm_projector.weight'])
        print('mm_projector bias:', weights['mm_projector.bias'] == LLaVA_00002_weights['model.mm_projector.bias'])

        # 1. vec2word: Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=32035, bias=False)
        LLaMA_lm_haed = weights.pop('lm_head.weight')
        LLaMA_lm_haed = LLaMA_lm_haed[-self.config.num_new_tokens:]
        self.lm_head.weight.data[-self.config.num_new_tokens:] = LLaMA_lm_haed
        original_LLaMA_lm_head = self.original_lm_head_value
        self.lm_head.weight.data[:-self.config.num_new_tokens] = original_LLaMA_lm_head
        print('Matching language model head:', self.lm_head.weight.data[0] == self.original_LLM_language_model_head_0)

        # 2. word2vec: Embedding(32035, 4096)
        LLaMA_word2vec = weights.pop('model.embed_tokens.weight')
        LLaMA_word2vec = LLaMA_word2vec[-self.config.num_new_tokens:]
        self.model.embed_tokens.weight.data[-self.config.num_new_tokens:] = LLaMA_word2vec
        original_LLaMA_embed_tokens = self.origin_inp_embedding
        self.model.embed_tokens.weight.data[:-self.config.num_new_tokens] = original_LLaMA_embed_tokens
        print('Matching word embedding:', self.model.embed_tokens.weight.data[0] == self.original_LLM_word_embedding_0)

        # 3. mm_projector
        mm_projector_param = {'weight': weights.pop('mm_projector.weight'), 'bias': weights.pop('mm_projector.bias')}
        self.mm_projector.load_state_dict(mm_projector_param, strict=True)

        # 4. SD_Query and SD_Qformer -> remove 'sd_qformer.'
        self.sd_query_tokens.data = weights.pop('sd_query_tokens').float()
        self.sd_qformer.load_state_dict({k[len('sd_qformer.'):]: v for k, v in weights.items()})
        print('Loading embeddings for Qformer checkpoint:', self.sd_qformer.load_state_dict({k[len('sd_qformer.'):]: v for k, v in weights.items()}, strict=True))

Could you help me solving this problem? Thanks a lot!
